# "Refreshing" column header names in QT model

Tags: qt, qt4, qt4.7, qt4.6

Does anyone know how you "refresh" the names of the columns (the column headers) in QT?

I have code that, in certain cases, changes the name of a column.

```
model_ptr->header_list.replace( 1, "Bank #" );
```

Another example:

```
model_ptr->header_list.replace( 1, "Credit Union #" );
```

However this is only being refreshed when I actually click on the column header to sort by that column.  I would like it to update without having to click on the column header.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using the model's

```
void setHeaderData(int section, Qt::Orientation orientation, const QVariant & value, int role = Qt::EditRole)
```

method should cause the view to update. Assuming your view's header is connected to the model's `headerDataChanged()` signal.